# Use of LinkedIn for jobs and links

Tags: opportunity, job, promotion, social-network, career

Hello

This might be a silly question to ask, but for the sake of curiosity about experience of others...

How do you use LinkedIn for:

1) Finding jobs

2) Finding people with whom you talk or meet later, and collaborate

3) any other sound-related useful applications

(in assumption that at least one of the listed is possible in reality)

Is there any general strategy of use?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, avoid just adding people randomly and pitching to them. This not too subtle approach will definitely yield zero results. And it's against website policies.

You can join various groups and contribute with insight, however. That's where you make useful connections with whom you can discuss possible work later on.

I can't say I found jobs advertised on Linkedin, but it has brought me several clients so far.

As for the video that Rene posted, the sarcasm is exaggerated in there.

Comment: +1 for participating in groups! I used to participate a lot, learned quite a bit, and it led to more personal messages with nice and knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 3):

I moved to LA a little over a year ago and used linkedin to have my friends introduce me to folks they know in LA. It really helped me find friends and connections. Many did lead to work as well. I think the trick is to make your goal just getting to know folks and to learn from them, share knowledge with them, and garner advice. You can't roll up on a stranger and ask them to hire you. But if people know you, can count on you as a resource, and enjoy your company, they will let you know if they have heard of something. And you may even be able to hook them up as well. It is always great when you can plant someone you know and trust in a good place. It is good karma and a good investment for your future as well.

Answer (score 1):

[youtube]NcfXij6t4LA[/youtube]

:)